# How to extract props from response.data with get method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to return the prop name from this api https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/france but the console return only undefined. Somebody can help-me?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedCountry === '0'){
      return
    }
    axios.get<Country>(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/france`).then(response => {
      const {name}  = response.data
      console.log(name)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the data returned from the service is an array, you should read the name prop of response.data[0]

```js
useEffect(() => {
if (selectedCountry === '0') {
  return 
} 

axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/france`).then(response => {
   const {name}  = response.data[0]
   console.log(name)
 })
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from that GET request is an array:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "France",
        ...
    }
]
```

Since the response returned is an array, so you need to index the first item.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedCountry === '0') {
    return 
  } 
  axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/france')
    .then(response => {
      const { name } = response.data[0] 
      console.log(name) 
    })
})
```

In the future, you can try printing the entire response first to make sure you understand the shape of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Observing the returned data, response data is an array instead of an object.

```
[{"name":"France","topLevelDomain":[".fr"],"alpha2Code":"FR","alpha3Code":"FRA","callingCodes":["33"],"capital":"Paris","altSpellings":["FR","French Republic","République française"],"region":"Europe","subregion":"Western Europe","population":66710000,"latlng":[46.0,2.0],"demonym":"French","area":640679.0,"gini":32.7,"timezones":["UTC-10:00","UTC-09:30","UTC-09:00","UTC-08:00","UTC-04:00","UTC-03:00","UTC+01:00","UTC+03:00","UTC+04:00","UTC+05:00","UTC+11:00","UTC+12:00"],"borders":["AND","BEL","DEU","ITA","LUX","MCO","ESP","CHE"],"nativeName":"France","numericCode":"250","currencies":[{"code":"EUR","name":"Euro","symbol":"€"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"fr","iso639_2":"fra","name":"French","nativeName":"français"}],"translations":{"de":"Frankreich","es":"Francia","fr":"France","ja":"フランス","it":"Francia","br":"França","pt":"França","nl":"Frankrijk","hr":"Francuska","fa":"فرانسه"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/fra.svg","regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"EU","name":"European Union","otherAcronyms":[],"otherNames":[]}],"cioc":"FRA"}]
```

so you should treat response data as an array, like this

```
axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/france').
    then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        const [extractedData]  = response.data //response.data is an array, and you extract the content to extractedData
        const {name, topLevelDomain}= extractedData //extractedData is an object, so you can use braces to visit fields with their name 
        console.log(data)
        console.log(name)
        console.log(topLevelDomain)
    })
```